# Unsupported driver in laravel 4 when using laravel-oci8 package

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am currently trying to use the [laravel-oci8 package](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8) to connect to an oracle DB, I am receiving the error `Unsupported driver [pdo-via-oci8]` from laravel. it seems that the package may not have updated the list of available drivers? Is there a step I am missing to get this driver to be accessible?

I have followed the read.me on github exactly.Also this is not a php error about a missing driver it is laravel specific. I have OCI8 enabled in php.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is already fixed. Just in-case anyone have encountered the same issue.
Please refer to the this link https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/2

Regards,